# Detaching a directory to be modified as a branch elsewere using Git

Tags: git

Let's say my project is laid out as follows:

```
MyProject/
├── Examples
│   ├── ExamplesA
│   ├── ExamplesB
│   └── ExamplesC
└── TheLibrary
```

So there is this awesome library I've developed and a few usage examples which I would like to be distributed along with the library.

The thing is, the library, and that library alone has to be checked into a TFS repository. At the same time, my boss asked me to keep a copy of the project as it is so that it can be used later on.

The `MyProject` directory is a Git repository, of course. I was thinking about branching a single directory (namely, `MyProject/TheLibrary`), but how do I do that using Git? I've read about `git-subtree`, but I'm afraid I got lost somewhere in the jungle of endless `pull`s and `push`es. Could somebody help me with that?

Ideally, I would love to have two branches: `master` with the whole project in it, and `tfs` with the contents of the `MyProject/TheLibrary` folder. Then I would create development branches and merge them to both of these branches above. Is that or something similar possible using Git?

Comment: I don't see how this is not a dupe of all the previous questions about this, but I admit it's complicated, and I wrote it up as a script: https://gist.github.com/larsmans/caa4a9519bfd481da9f9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is how I did it.

I `split`ted `TheLibrary` to the `TheLibrary` branch using

```
git subtree split -P TheLibrary -b TheLibrary
```

and then I made a separate branch for maintaing a copy of `TheLibrary` in TFS or wherever.

```
git branch TheLibrary-tfs TheLibrary
```

So then I simply `clone`d the repository into my TFS workspace and checked out the `TheLibrary-tfs` branch.

Whenever I make TFS-specific change, I simply `commit` and `push` it and it's saved in my local folder outside of the TFS repository.

Whenever I need to make a TFS-unrelated change, I do it in my local folder in the `master` branch and then `push` using

```
git subtree push -P TheLibrary . TheLibrary
```

so that the change is propagated to the `TheLibrary` branch. Then I merge the changes to the `TheLibrary-tfs` branch. Finally, I simply navigate to my TFS workspace and `pull` the changes from my local folder. Complicated, but works and appears to be just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to move the latest version of `TheLibrary` to a new branch you can do it in this way (I assume you are on branch master):

```
$ git rm -rf Examples
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/tfs
$ git commit -m 'New Branch for TheLibrary'
```

now switch back to the master and remove `TheLibrary`

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rm -rf TheLibrary
$ git commit -m 'TheLibrary moved to branch tfs'
```

The result will look like this

```
Repository View                     Working Directory View

o-----o-----o-----o                 MyProject/
                  ^                   ├── Examples
                  |                    ├── ExamplesA
                master                 ├── ExamplesB
                                       └── ExamplesC


o                                    MyProject/
^                                     └── TheLibrary
|
tfs
```

So what happens...

1. `git rm -rf Examples` remove the `Examples` and it's sub directories from your working directory and the index (staging area)
2. `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/tfs` let the `HEAD` reference point to a new branch called `tfs`
3. `git commit -m 'New Branch for TheLibrary'` Commits the index (now only contains `TheLibrary`) as a new commit of the `tfs` branch.
4. `git checkout master` switch back to the master
5. `git rm -rf TheLibrary` remove `TheLibrary` from the working dir and the index.
6. `git commit -m 'TheLibrary moved to branch tfs'` make a new commit on the master that does not contain `TheLibrary` anymore and a commit message that points to the new location.

Comment: Sorry for responding so much later than you posted the answer, but I was stuck looking for a solution. Yours doesn't satisfies my needs, I'm afraid, because I wanted to maintain a copy of `MyLibrary` in every branch of the repository.

Comment: In case you're interested, I managed to achieve that (see the answer somewhere around).